# Formatting in NetBeans: CSS specific

Tags: netbeans, formatting, indentation

I would like to use spaces for indentation for most code, but use tabs for indentation in CSS. In Visual Studio and Notepad++, you can configure this for all languages. But in NetBeans (setup for PHP), I can only select "All languages" or "PHP".

Is there a way to make other languages have specific formatting settings (specifically CSS)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Depending on the IDE modules that you have, you will see PHP, Java or All Languages. But there is no way to change formatting styles for CSS-only in Netbeans. This feature has been asked a few times already in the Netbeans users list, but has not been implemented yet.

Comment: These are the relevant bug reports: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=144164 and https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=242654

Comment: Come on, this bug is from 2008, and 10 years later still not resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no available setting for css formatting or xml, jsp you can set the 'Language' to 'All Language'. It will apply on all the languages that has NetBeans support. If the case is you have other formatting setting specific on Javascript or any language that on 'Language' menu, you can override it.